# CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows Directory

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, cmd, parallels

Just coding in C++ on visual studios and when i run the program it executes and then outputs this.

I believe it may be because i am running VS on parallels? Could this possibly be why? and if so, any way to get rid of it?

error message:

```
'\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Object_Oriented_Coursework\Object_Oriented_Coursework' 
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. 
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows Directory.
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276 Is your code being stored on a network drive?

Comment: I get the same from a VS 2022 project with custom (cmd.exe) build steps when I clone from git under WSL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

without more details... it looks like you've opened your sln file from a UNC path... which means the execution when running from within VS should use the UNC path but it is not allowed.

> Solution to be clear: Instead of accessing \share\folder\file.sln,
> create a drive Z: that maps \share\folder and then open Z:\file.sln

Comment: my answer is valid. map a network drive to your path and use it

Comment: how do i got about doing that? sorry for seeming oblivious to simple things :)

Comment: no worries i think i have solved it, i had it mapped to the Z: drive but was opening it locally. Thanks for your help

Comment: Solution to be clear: Instead of accessing `\\share\folder\file.sln`, create a drive `Z:` that maps `\\share\folder` and then open `Z:\file.sln`